# Ajax call populate Typeahead Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is to get a json object via Ajax and populate the Bootstrap Typeahead with just one kind of value.

Here is my code:

```
nameTypeHead: function () {
        var _self = this,
            searchInput = $('#nameTypeHead'),
            arr = [];

        function getArray() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/AutoComplete',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { searchText: searchInput.val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function () {
                        arr.push(this.Name);
                    });
                    return arr;
                }
            });
        }

        searchInput.typeahead({
            source: getArray()
        });
    }
```

I receive the error that **arr is null**

I also tried with `.parseJSON()` but with no success:

```
$.each($.parseJSON(data), function () {
   arr.push(this.Name);
});
```

What can I do to show just the value Name of my Json Object in the Typeahed?

If in the Ajax Success I put `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` it alert correctly my Json Object.

Comment: `success` callback doesn't have to return anything, being it an async call - check [this example instead](https://gist.github.com/1866577).

Comment: Also if I remove `return arr;` it doesn't work...

Comment: From your link I can not understand CoffeeScript. Where I should declare `property: "name"`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I made it from scratch:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({

    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.getJSON(
            'path/to/lookup',
            { query: query },
            function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
    }

});
```

Where `data` is a simple JSON array like:

```
 [
   "John",
   "Jane",
   "Alfredo",
   "Giovanni",
   "Superman"
 ]
```

If your `data` array has got a different structure, just rearrange it before passing it to `process()` method.

You can find a live example [here](http://moonwave99.webfactional.com/typeahead/).

EDIT - based on your json data:

```
[
    {'id':'0', 'name':'John'},
    {'id':'1', 'name':'Jane'}, 
    {'id':'2', 'name':'Alfredo'},
    ...
}
```

The `getJSON` callback becomes:

```
function (data) {
    return process(data.map((x => x.name));
});
```

Comment: just one question, why I should add in the url `+query` ?!?

Comment: and my console log say: TypeError: typeahead.process is not a function

Comment: Well you are asking your server for stuff based on what you are typing - `query` string.

Comment: and I pass the value using `data: { ... : ... }`

Comment: still doesn't work. and there are no { } in your code... how can it work?!?

Comment: Dared to see my example's source? You just have to change it with your `/Home/AutoComplete` url.

Comment: and my json is not simple like your... is a complex one and I need to get only the Name value.

Comment: Please provide an example of your JSON.

Comment: `[{'id':'0', 'name':'John'}, {'id':'1', 'name':'Jane'}, {'id':'2', 'name':'Alfredo'}, {etc...}]`

Comment: Not that your json is very complex :P See my latest edit, have a nice evening!

Comment: Great answer. But you should write `process(data); return;` instead of `return process(data);`

Comment: 9 years later. Still deserves a thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Checkout this gist. Does autocomplete, deals with fast typers, and caches

https://gist.github.com/mrgcohen/5062352

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much more sophisticated and efficient. Thanks for gist!

Comment: Came up with my own solution for this, but was not that great and I was unhappy with it. This one is nice and simple. -- Note for others, you barley need to add or do anything just copy in the code, change the URL of your `getJSON`. Works out of the box.

Comment: Thanks glad you like it. There are some good gist forks of it too.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:-

**HTML Setup :**

```
<!-- HTML Setup-->
<input type="text" id="my-typeahead" />
```

**Javascript :**

```
/* 
example remote-data-source
[
  {
    id:1,
    name:'Batman'
  },{
    id:2,
    name:'Superman'
  } 
]
*/

$('#my-typeahead').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    name: 'myDataset',
    source: function(str, sync, async) {
        // abstracting out the "REST call and processing" in a seperate function
        restCall(str, async);
    },
    templates: {
        suggestion: function(user) {
            return '<div>' + user.name + '</div>';
        },
        pending: '<div>Please wait...</div>'
    }
});

// The function that will make the REST call and return the data
function restCall(str, async) {
    return $.ajax('http://url-for-remote-data-source/query?name=' + str, {
        // headers and other setting you wish to set-up
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        // response
        success: function(res) {
            //processing data on response with 'async'
            return async(res.data);
        }
    });
}
```

**References:**

`Typeahead Docs - Datasets` : https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

`Jquery **$.ajax()**` : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Good Luck.

Comment: This works but make sure about the format of res variable in success response for your specific ajax call.