# Handling objects with Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using the Bootstrap Typeahead plugin like so:

```
$('#Organisation').typeahead({
            source: function (query, process) {
                return $.get(AppURL + 'Organisations/Manage/SearchByName/',
                {
                    term: query
                },
                function (data) {
                    var results = [];
                    var fullResults = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        results.push(item.label);
                        fullResults.push({
                            id: item.ID,
                            label: item.label
                        });
                    });

                    return process(results);


                });
            },
            updater: function (selection) {
                $('#OrganisationID').val(selection);
            }
        });
```

I have two returned arrays, this is because Typeahead ONLY wants a list of strings instead of an object. The second array contains both the label and id.

Once a user selects an item from the list I need to get the ID from this selection and then use it to insert into a hidden field. But the selection will just be the name, as the ID can't be passed through via Typeahead.

Any ideas on how I can solve this?

An example of the two returned arrays:

results: `["Organisation 1","Organisation 2"]`

fullResults: `[{"label":"Organisation 1","ID":2},{"label":"Organisation 2","ID":1}]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax call popolate Typeahead Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621823/ajax-call-popolate-typeahead-bootstrap)

Comment: @moonwave99 That question doesn't explain how to get the selected value I require from the object. As typeahead only deals with simple selects of strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching around a bit on the net I found [this](http://tatiyants.com/how-to-use-json-objects-with-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead/) HowTo. In it they do what you want, but with no ajax.

You should also be able to return a object, from the source function, but you would need to re-implement all the helper functions of typeahead.

Comment: The link @fredrik listed above shows examples of how to re-implement all the helper functions; I tested it on a fresh, bare-bones HTML page with nothing but some input elements and basic styling, referencing only jQuery and the bootstrap-typeahead.js file from the Bootstrap Git project, and it worked great.

Comment: The only problem with this method is that it doesn't take into account if the display strings are not unique. You will always get the first result that matches with no way to select any further down the list.

Answer (score 3):

You [cannot normally use JSON objects](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/7298) directly within Bootstrap Typeahead (2.x), but you can easily tweak it to do so.  The wording of this question should help for people to find this in one place.  Other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072956/how-to-avoid-to-display-json-string-with-custom-typeahead) have asked similar things, but not identical to the way that you did.

```
var typeahead = control.typeahead({ /* ... */ }).data('typeahead');

// manually override select and render
//  (change attr('data-value' ...) to data('value' ...))
//  otherwise both functions are exact copies
typeahead.select = function() {
    var val = this.$menu.find('.active').data('value')
    this.$element.val(this.updater(val)).change()
    return this.hide()
};
typeahead.render = function(items) {
    var that = this

    items = $(items).map(function (i, item) {
        i = $(that.options.item).data('value', item)
        i.find('a').html(that.highlighter(item))
        return i[0]
    });

    items.first().addClass('active')
    this.$menu.html(items)
    return this
};
```

Other than that, you must override `highlighter`, `matcher`, `sorter`, and `updater`, but those can done via the options passed into the typeahead, where the passed in `item`(s) are now your JSON objects.

When selecting `item`s, `updater` is called, which is how you set the value *and* use the JSON data:

```
updater: function (item) {
    someGlobalValue = item.id;

    // must return a normal string; sets the textbox value
    return item.name;
}
```

This also means that you don't need to do anything fancy to associate, or otherwise "remember" the items external to Typeahead referenced example in the other answer. The most annoying part of the whole overriding process is rewriting the `sorter` in every use.

Answer (score 3):

I have an ugly solution...

I needed to be able to search into the title but to finally put the ID into the text input...

my JSON is

```
[
{"id": 1, "title": "Foo foo foo"},
{"id": 2, "title": "Bar bar bar"},
...
]
```

and my call...

```
$(function() {
    $.get("path/to/data.json", function(data){
          $(".typeahead").typeahead({
              "source": data,
              "displayText": function(item){
                  // OMG ugly !!! :p
                  if (item.id == undefined) return item;
                  return item.title + ' (' + item.id + ')';  
              },
              "updater": function(item) {
                  return item.id;
              }});
    }, 'json');
});
```

All is working as usual but when you click on the selected item, only the id is put into the field...

done ! ugly but done...

Tested with https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Consider rewriting "matcher", "sorter", "updater" and "highlighter" functions just like it was described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959406/593415

This really does a trick so that you could manipulate objects with Bootstrap Typeahead (2.x)