# Typehead.js Updater Function

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

On bootstrap typehead i want to display selected data to the field.

```
     $('#typeahead').typeahead({
      source: function(query, process) {
     $.ajax({
              url: 'data.php',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: 'query=' + query,
          success: function(data) {
          objects = [];
              map = {};

                 $.each(data, function(i, object) {
                    map[object.client_name] = object;
                    objects.push(object.client_name);
                    });

                     process(objects);

    },
        updater: function(item) {
             $('#c_id').val(map[item].client_id);
             return item;
                 }
       });
           }              });
```

Valaue return form data.php

{"client_id":"2024","client_name":"thomas","client_company":"infos"}

i want to display client id in  client id field

Comment: you can access client id with data.client_id if i recall correctly

Comment: i want to just disply that value in text field

Answer (score 0):

*after the comments*

Suppose you have this html code:

```
<textarea id="myTextArea">
</textarea>
```

you can use this code (where you have the $each function)

```
$('#myTextArea').val(data.client_id);
```

or maybe is .html() and not .val() i do not remember, need a little testing... sorry =)

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked on stackoverflow. Please check the following link

[Ajax call populate Typeahead Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621823/ajax-call-populate-typeahead-bootstrap)

This should definitely solve your problem.