# jQuery drop down list / auto-complete w/ over 200,000 items

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I'm pretty much experiencing "coding-block".  I have a SQL database, and one of the tables contains over 200,000 records.  I will have some sort of drop down list (textbox with autocomplete maybe).  I don't want all 200,000 in my drop down list (for obvious reasons) - I'm kind of envisioning a jQuery solution where you start typing (autocomplete) and the web server queries the database to pull in relevant records to populate the drop down list.  Say, type the first 3 letters and that's when my code will make a call to get records from the database that match the first 3 letters of what I typed in.  I don't have much experience with jQuery's auto-complete control.  Where would I even start with this?

Comment: You can also use the typeahed plugin, see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621823/ajax-call-populate-typeahead-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete should solve your problem, but it is my favorite http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please consider adding some code/better explanation that how it may solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, tanks for the feedback ;)